# Как перебрать данные в БД с помощью цикла for и вывести тг боту данные

Tags: python, sql, aiogram, for

Доброй ночи, подскажите, пожалуйста, как в БД перебрать данные с помощью цикла `for` и вывести тг-боту данные из БД. Суть БД проста.

Тг-бот занимается продажей кроссовок, есть админ-панель, которая может записать с помощью FSM данные о модели кроссовка в БД (модель, бренд, цена, фото).

Я сделал, что если в БД есть строка данных, в которых бренд = nike и пользователь нажмёт на нужную кнопку, выведется инфа о кроссовке, но эта инфа выглядит некрасиво:

```
([('airmax', 140, 'nike', 'AgACAgIAAxkBAAIEOWQ5T8t954DEcyBWWpAIkjAJ7pApAALcyjEbN2zQSacLUAgG8y7iAQADAgADeQADLwQ')])
```

Мне надо как-то с помощью цикла перебрать эти данные и вывести их в нормальном виде, по типу:

```
brend = hike
price = 140
model = airmax
photo = фотка кроссовка
```

Код БД:

```
    import sqlite3 as sq
    
    db = sq.connect('tgdb.db')
    cur = db.cursor()
    
    
async def db_start():
    cur.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS items("
                "i_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
                "model TEXT,"
                "price INTEGER,"
                "photo_it TEXT,"
                "brang TEXT)")
    db.commit()
    
    
    
    def db_table_items(model: str, price: int, brang: str, photo_it: str):
        cur.execute('INSERT INTO items (model, price, brang, photo_it) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)',
                       (model, price, brang, photo_it))
        db.commit()
    
    
    brend_name = "nike"
    item_nike = cur.execute(
            "SELECT model, price, brang, photo_it FROM items WHERE brang = ?",
            (brend_name,),
    ).fetchall()
```

Код хэндлера и функции, которые выводят данные о кроссовке найк и могут запомнит мои введёные данные:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
    @dp.message_handler(state=Form.photo, content_types=types.ContentType.PHOTO)
    async def process_text(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
        async with state.proxy() as data:
            photo_item = data['photo'] = message.photo[-1].file_id
        send_shoes = f"brend: {data['brend']}\n" \
        f"model: {data['model']}\n" \
        f"price: {data['price']}"
        brend_item  = f"{data['brend']}"
        model_item = f"{data['model']}"
        price_item = f"{data['price']}"
        await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, send_shoes)
        await bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, photo=photo_item)
        db.db_table_items(brang=brend_item, price=price_item, model=model_item, photo_it=photo_item)
        await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, item_nike)
```